# My program keeps waiting dont and does not even show the first printf

Tags: c, ipc

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>



typedef struct{long type;char resultado[10];} MsgAnswerLoginStruct;


typedef struct{long tipo;int meupid;char login[20];char password[20];}MsgReqLoginStruct;


main(){

printf("i am here");

int msg_id, status;
MsgReqLoginStruct msg;
MsgAnswerLoginStruct msg2;

msg_id = msgget(2000, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
if(msg_id == -1){
    printf("erro\n");
    exit(1);
}


status = msgrcv(msg_id, &msg, sizeof(msg) - sizeof(long) , 1,  0);
if(status < 0){
    printf("erro2\n");
    exit(1);
}


printf("Tentativa de Autenticação de PID = %d\n", msg.meupid);

}
```

here is my problem, this is a program that receives messages from the IPC, but he keeps waiting even when I am trying to send from another process..
And I put that printf to debug.. It doesnt appear on my console?! why ?
when I run program it just keeps waiting..
Thanks in advance guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not flusing the buffer. It's likely `stdout` is line buffered in your implementation.

Try:

```
printf("i am here\n");
                  ^^
```

Or

```
printf("i am here");
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: GUYS FOR GOD SAKE! You are amazing here on this website!! You guys answer in less than 5 minutes! JEZ! 
Thanks alot mate! You solved my issue!
Great community here on stackoverflow! Just saying !
Bye and thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `strace` to understand what system calls a program is doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to your specific question, but you should really handle msgget/msgrcv errors better.  Both functions set errno when they fail, and you can use that to provide useful information to the user about the nature of the error.  Just write:

```
if( status < 0 ) {
    perror( "msgrcv" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

perror is the simplest way to get information from errno.  If you want a more sophisticated error message, you can use strerror.  For example,

```
fprintf( stderr, "Some error message: %s\n", strerror( errno ));
```

In either case, the error message goes to stderr, rather than stdout.  You do not want error messages going to stdout.